# Applying Word Quick Style Set to an old document

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I created/saved a Word Quick Style Set. I applied the set to different documents, old and new, and it seemed to work just fine.

Then I installed the Quick Style Set onto a second computer. (I also copied and installed the Normal.dotm file from the first computer.)

The style set appears in the style set list. When I open a new document and choose the Quick Style Set, the styles work fine. But when I open an old document and try to apply (or choose) the Quick Style Set, nothing happens. The styles in the set are not added to my document.

Why isn't the Style Set applying to the old document?